# Ag-grid hide rowGroupPanel dynamically

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

[image]

I tried to hide/show this rowGroupPanel dynamically by using a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked, then I'll update it as 'always' else 'never' in gridOptions as shown below but it failed.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no inbuilt method by AG-Grid to do this nor it is documented in documentation anywhere but you can use simple JavaScript to target the `rowGroupPanel` element and control the `visibility` of it. here is a simple [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rJxUm2t8s9THHBIg)